# Create Hyperlink to view in another app with djangoRESTframework

Tags: django, hyperlink, django-rest-framework

If I have two apps, with separate urls.py files, how can I reference the view from on app in another so that I can include references with a HyperLinkedField?

Let's define two models in separate apps

```
class Document(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    text = models.TextField()

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
```

Now the Serializers

```
class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_link = HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name="user-detail")

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('user_link', 'text')
```

and now for the relevant urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', 
        views.UserDetail.as_view()
        name='user-detail'
    ),
)
```

Comment: can you share some code ?

Comment: Is that enough? or should I add the view?

Comment: can you not just have a `get_absolute_url` in the models, and call `{{item.get_absolute_url}}` ?

Comment: No, I cannot because the two models are in different apps, and in my implementation, one of them is built with mongoengine instead of the standard Django ORM